# What is this new extra lock screen and what is the app/setting causing it?

Tags: settings

Anybody know what app or setting that causes this *EXTRA lock screen on my LG G6 (Android 7.0)? It just started 3 days ago. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

*After swiping UP from the bottom of the screen, it takes me to my normal/original lock s creen.

[image]

Comment: It looks almost like what I have on Oreo although mine is Lineage.  Are you sure you aren't on Oreo?

Comment: It's probably daydream . Check in your settings if you have set daydream to clock